# Is there another way to avoid name clash in nested multido?

Tags: pstricks, programming, multido, programming-tools

### Constraints

- I want to use the same name for inner and outer loop.
- I am reluctant to append `@` and make use of `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.

Is there any name-spacing construct to use?

### MWE

The following code will not produce the correct result as the two `\i` clash.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\def\Triangle(#1)#2{{\rput(#1){\multido{\i=0+1}{#2}{\multips(\i,0)(!.5 3 sqrt 2 div){\numexpr#2-\i\relax}{\pspolygon(1,0)(!.5 3 sqrt 2 div)}}}}}


\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\FPset\N{4}
\FPeval\Width{(N-1)*(N+2)/2+N}
\FPeval\Height{round(root(2,3)*N/2:6)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Width,\Height)
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\N}{\Triangle(!\i\space 1 sub \i\space 2 add mul 2 div 0){\i}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The correct output is as follows.

[image]

Comment: You know you can use `\iA` and `\iB`...

Comment: @Werner: `\A!=\iB` that disobeys the given constraint. I know this.

Comment: Strange request though, since using two different counters (`\iA` and `\iB`, say) is *far* easier than completely redefining the inner-workings of `\multido` to keep track of the nesting, don't you think?

Comment: @Werner: This question concentrates more on the theoretical aspect than the current practical use. I want to avoid remembering the already used variables when using nested `multido`. I also don't want to clutter the code with `@` that consumes more keystrokes. :-)

Comment: Would you use the same index for a summation inside a summation? I bet not. Different variables should have different symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding name clashes is achieved by using unique names for each identifier in the loop. However, in this case, passing arguments directly on to the inner `\multido` means they're not expanded until used, at which time they also need to be set. "Pre-expansion" (declaring macros that contain an expanded version of the arguments) helps avoid this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
\SpecialCoor
\def\Triangle(#1)#2{%
  \edef\firstarg{#1}\edef\secondarg{#2}% pre-expand #1 and #2
  \rput(\firstarg){\multido{\i=0+1}{\secondarg}{\multips(\i,0)(!.5 3 sqrt 2 div){\numexpr\secondarg-\i\relax}{\pspolygon(1,0)(!.5 3 sqrt 2 div)}}}}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\FPset\N{4}
\FPeval\Width{(N-1)*(N+2)/2+N}
\FPeval\Height{round(root(2,3)*N/2:6)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Width,\Height)
  \multido{\i=1+1}{\N}{\Triangle(!\i\space 1 sub \i\space 2 add mul 2 div 0){\i}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\xintFor` loop from package [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint). One does not have to worry then about the name used for the iterated variable.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\SpecialCoor

% inside a macro, the # for an \xintFor must be doubled
%
\def\Triangle(#1)#2{{\rput(#1)%
                    {\xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq {0}{#2-1}}\do
                     {\multips(##1,0)(!.5 3 sqrt 2 div)%
                         {\numexpr#2-##1\relax}%
                         {\pspolygon(1,0)(!.5 3 sqrt 2 div)}}}}}


\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\FPset\N{4}
\FPeval\Width{(N-1)*(N+2)/2+N}
\FPeval\Height{round(root(2,3)*N/2:6)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Width,\Height)
    \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\N}} \do
    {\Triangle(!#1 1 sub #1 2 add mul 2 div 0){#1}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: triangles]

One can furthermore compute in real time `\Width` and `\Height` with [xintexpr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xintexpr}% loads xinttools automatically
\SpecialCoor

% inside a macro, the # for an \xintFor must be doubled
%
\def\Triangle(#1)#2{{\rput(#1)%
                    {\xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq {0}{#2-1}}\do
                     {\multips(##1,0)(!.5 3 sqrt 2 div)%
                         {\numexpr#2-##1\relax}%
                         {\pspolygon(1,0)(!.5 3 sqrt 2 div)}}}}}

\providecommand\firstofone [1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\def\N {4}
%
% we use \xintthenumexpr for the width as it guarantees 
% integer format on output
%
% we use \firstofone to hide parentheses and other things from pspicture
% 
\begin{pspicture}(\firstofone{\xintthenumexpr (\N-1)*(\N+2)/2+\N\relax},%
                  \firstofone{\xinttheexpr round(sqrt(3)*\N/2,6)\relax})
    \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\N}} \do
    {\Triangle(!#1 1 sub #1 2 add mul 2 div 0){#1}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

A `\firstofone` trick had to be used to hide the parentheses. For some reason, putting the whole `xintexpr`-essions inside braces does not work with `pspicture`. Braces *inside* `\xintexpr .. \relax` have special meaning, one could do `\xintthenumexpr{\xinttheexpr..\relax}\relax` for the width for example but this is admittedly complicated.